# Is there a way to check read buffer is remaining?

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I'm developing websocket with epoll.

referenced: https://github.com/eranyanay/1m-go-websockets/blob/master/3_optimize_ws_goroutines/server.go

It read one time in conn.ReadMessage() when epoll event triggered.

But if there are two websocket packets, conn.ReadMessage() doesn't read all packets. just one packet is read.

**How can I check if there are remaining bytes in buffers after conn.ReadMessage()?** to call conn.ReadMessage until buffer is empty.

The epoll default is level triggered but the event called only once. if It calls conn.ReadMessage() just once, then epoll doesn't triggered even though bytes remaining in the buffer.

Comment: The package uses a [bufio.Reader](https://godoc.org/bufio#Reader) internally.  Fork the package and add a method to expose [the count of buffered bytes in the Reader](https://godoc.org/bufio#Reader.Buffered).

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thank you. but I think it is the last solution..

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/gobwas/ws. It's designed from the ground up to support the epoll scenario.